# i want make a csv file with matlab but my csv is strange

Tags: matlab, csv, makefile, concatenation

i did..set value. station = cell, header = char, data = double

```
station = {'st';,'qe';,'qr';}
header = ('where QE QR');
data =  [10 15;20 25;30 35;]
```

i did unify data type station, data to concat. data2 = cell

```
ofn = 'set.csv';
ofid=fopen(ofn,'w');
hdr = header;
fmt = '%s %d %d\n';

data = num2cell(data);
data2 = [station data];

fprintf(ofid,'%s\n',hdr);
fprintf(ofid,fmt,data2{:});
fclose(ofid);
```

i want make csv like image.

[image]

but my result was this..

[image]

plz, i want know what was problem. help me..

Comment: CSV stands for “comma separated values”. Try putting commas in between the values, instead of spaces.

Comment: i did change data =  [10,15;20,25;30,35;] but result is same..

Comment: Cris meant commas i format: `fmt = '%s, %d, %d\n';'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write a CSV file I recommend you to use

```
writetable(table,'filename.csv')
```

This function outputs the table in CSV format.

In your case you could use

```
station = {'st';,'qe';,'qr';}
data =  [10 15;20 25;30 35;]

st.where=station;
st.qe=data(:,1);
st.qr=data(:,2);
writetable(struct2table(st),'output.csv')
```